# How to use AWS Amplify env vars in gatsby-config.js?

Tags: encryption, environment-variables, config, gatsby, aws-amplify

I am building an app with GatsbyJS. I am using environment variables in my gatsby-config.js. GatsbyJS app builds fine locally, by using .env.* files. However, when building from AWS Amplify it complains about an invalid value retrieved from environment variables. Indeed, it seems that when using `process.env.MY_VAR` inside gatsby-config.js the value retrieved is encrypted (as per AWSAmplify docs).

I tried with hardcoding the value of the env. var to confirm that encryption was the problem.
The error that I am getting is:
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: 6fbaeed85a68.`

Which clearly indicates that the value retrieved from `process.env.HOSTNAME` is `6fbaeed85a68` and not the actual value that I provided in AWS Amplify web's interface.

Below is my gatsby-js.config:

```js
const path = require(`path`);
const queries = require('./src/utils/algolia');
const feedOptions = require('./src/utils/feed');
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: new URL(process.env.HOSTNAME).href,
    title: `APP_TITLE`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-kentico-cloud`,
      options: {
        deliveryClientConfig: {
          projectId: process.env.KENTICO_PROJECT_ID,
        },
        languageCodenames: process.env.KENTICO_LANGUAGES.split(';'),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-algolia`,
      options: {
        appId: process.env.GATSBY_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
        apiKey: process.env.ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY,
        queries,
        chunkSize: 10000,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `APP_NAME`,
        short_name: `APP_SHORT_NAME`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#dbdcd1`,
        theme_color: `#1ad2eb`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/logo-simple-transp-square-260x260.png`,
        include_favicon: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `images`),
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        includePaths: ['src/styles/_variables'],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mailchimp',
      options: {
        endpoint: process.env.MAILCHIMP_ENDPOINT,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link',
      options: {
        layout: require.resolve(`./src/layout`),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: feedOptions,
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`,
      options: {
        id: process.env.GTM_CODE,
        includeInDevelopment: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I don't understand how I am supposed to retrieve env vars. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like adding GATSBY_ prefix to my variable fixes the issue. From the doc it is supposed to be used only when accessing variable from browser, so not too sure why it works.

Answer (score 2):

When adding environment variables to AWS Amplify App under App Setting -> Environment Variables, just prefix `GATSBY_` to all your environment variable names. Remember to change your code to use the new names.

Adding `GATSBY_` makes env variables accessible to browser javascript.

Read more about it in the [official documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript).